# Subsite excluded from root level search, can have its own search?

Tags: search

I have a site and few subsites under it. I want to exclude subsite-A from the search results, when searched from anywhere, from root or other subsites. And this excluded subsite-A should have its own search, results limited to itself.

I excluded this subsite-A using result source.
Query to exclude that site from search is: 
{searchTerms} -Path:{Site.Path}

Now if I search something in this excluded subsite, results are empty. I think the reason is because it is excluded from search.

I am trying to figure out if SharePoint 2013 allows this?
Can any one suggest me how to make this happen. Is there anyway this could be possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Path` managed property, here is an example how to configure a search query to exclude a specific site from a search results:

```
{searchTerms} Path<>https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project
```

where `Project` is a name of site we would like to exclude.

Some more examples how to configure search query to exclude a specific site from search results:

```
{searchTerms} SiteTitle<>Project


{searchTerms} Site<>https://contoso.sharepoint.com/project
```

### How to configure custom search settings for a site

- create a `Result Source` (per site scope)
- make it a Default Result Source for a site

Another option would be to create a custom search result page and set option  `Send queries to a custom results page URL` in `Search Settings`

Comment: Can the excluded site have its own search?

Comment: Sure, first option would be to create new Result Source per site level (Site Settings - Result Sources under Search group - New Result Source) and then make it a Default Result Source for a site.  
Another option would be to configure custom results page per site: Site Settings - Search Settings under Search group - un-check "Use the same results page settings as my parent." and specify custom search results page url configured to specific site

Comment: I used 
{searchTerms} -Path:{Site.Path} 
to root site to exclude its subsite from the search.
This query woeks fine in excluding the subsite, but if I search in this excluded site, results are empty

Comment: Now I excluded the subsite by adding query in root sites result sources and unchecked "Use the same results page settings as my parent" in excluded site and added a query {searchTerms} path:path in excluded site to limit the search to itself.
Will it work?

Comment: It still dint work

Comment: It is not enough just to disable the option  "Use the same results page settings as my parent", the custom search page have to be provided for that scenario. There is more simple solution (option 1 in my previous comment) 1) create a custom Result Source to include results ONLY for a specific sub site 2) Set this Result Source as a default sub site. That's it.

Comment: I tried, yet it dint work.